# Using URL and description i Workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

[image]I am creating a Variable to hold URL and Description. It is looking like this [%Current Item:URL%], [%Current Item:Title] (the Variable is set to String).

This is format is supposed to populated the URL field with the URL and the Description field with the Title, but it doesn't.

It just puts "URL", "Title" in both fields.

According to other guides it should work, so I don't understand what is wrong.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

According to you there is gotcha need to take care while updating/set hyperlink field in SharePoint.
Just check for variable (...) in the string builder dialog simply and put together:
 [%Current Item:URL%], [%Current Item:Name%]. 
The URL and display name is thus separated by a comma and space. Both of these are important.

Comment: Adding the Name field didn't work. It is the same problem. The two Lookups are seperated with a comma and a space.

Comment: Check the item does it have the value on which the workflow is running on, and the Name field is just for text you can choose any thing .

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But I removed the [%Current Item:Title%] and ran the Workflow, and it shows me the correct URL. So it is the correct value I am using in the workflow.

Comment: Use with [%Current Item:URL%], 'Document'

Comment: No, addin 'Document' does not work either. I have just tried to create two new lists and a simple workflow. But the same happens. This is how it looks like after the workflow has run: (it is the same thing if I write 'Document') "https://www.xxxxx.dk, Maria is testing"

Comment: attach an image of what you are trying, which may make us clear what to acheive

Comment: I have added a screen shot with the variable.

Comment: For fun I tried to add the URL lookup on it's own. And apparently it does show the description link to the URL, when the workflow has run. So I could actually use it alone, if it wasn't because some users don't add a description.